# Ruby official system names

Tags: ruby

How can I finf out the official system name (defined in rfc943 https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc943#ref-37 ) of the os with ruby?

Comment: Are you uncertain if you are on a TOPS10 or TOPS20 system or why do you want to know this? It feels kind of obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

If it's the hostname you are looking for then you can

```
require 'socket'
host = Socket.gethostname
```

but if it's actually one of the listed *OFFICIAL SYSTEM NAMES* in RFC943 then I think you are out of luck. The closest I can think of if the pre-defined global constant `RUBY_PLATFORM` but for me it says `i486-linux` and that's not one the *OPERATING SYSTEM ACRONYMS* in RFC810.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a:

```
system_name = `uname`.chop
```

or

```
hostname = `hostname`.chop
```

Note that its a backtick to execute a binary outside of the app. This does not work on non linux based systems ofcourse.

Comment: It works on OS X (and, I imagine, most Unix distributions), too.